# How can I dynamically add field in MapElements in apache_beam?

Tags: java, apache-beam

I would appreciate if someone could help me out writing java code for *apache_beam (2.13.0)* .

In *python* , you could **dynamically** add field using **1 to 1 mapping** of *Map* function.

### Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io.textio import WriteToText

def addoutput(line):
    return [line, "Its weekend!"]

with beam.Pipeline() as p:
    ( p
      | beam.Create(["blah"])
      | beam.Map(addoutput)
      | WriteToText(file_path_prefix="/tmp/sample")
    )
```

### Result

```
['blah', 'Its weekend!']
```

However, when I try to do same thing with java, I get an compile error in *maven*.

### Code

```
public class SampleTextIO
{
    static class AddFieldFn extends DoFn<String, String> {

        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(@Element String word, OutputReceiver<String> receiver) {

            receiver.output(word);
            receiver.output("Its weekend!");
        }
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        System.out.println( "Main class for DirectRunner" );

        // Pipeline create using default runner (DirectRunnter)
        // Interface: PipelineOptions
        PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();

        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

        // Example pcollection
        final List<String> LINES = Arrays.asList(
            "blah"
        );

        // Read lines from file
        p.apply(Create.of(LINES))
         .apply(MapElements.via(new AddFieldFn()))
         .apply(TextIO.write().to("/tmp/test-out"));

        p.run().waitUntilFinish();
    }
}
```

### Result

```
[ERROR] /home/ywatanabe/git/google-data-engineer/Data_Science_on_the_Google_Cloud_Platform/Ch04/java/directrunner/src/main/java/com/example/SampleTextIO.java:[43,28] no suitable method found for via(com.example.SampleTextIO.AddFieldFn)
[ERROR]     method org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements.<InputT,OutputT>via(org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.InferableFunction<InputT,OutputT>) is not applicable
[ERROR]       (cannot infer type-variable(s) InputT,OutputT
[ERROR]         (argument mismatch; com.example.SampleTextIO.AddFieldFn cannot be converted to org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.InferableFunction<InputT,OutputT>))
[ERROR]     method org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements.<InputT,OutputT>via(org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.SimpleFunction<InputT,OutputT>) is not applicable
[ERROR]       (cannot infer type-variable(s) InputT,OutputT
[ERROR]         (argument mismatch; com.example.SampleTextIO.AddFieldFn cannot be converted to org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.SimpleFunction<InputT,OutputT>))
[ERROR]     method org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements.via(org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ProcessFunction) is not applicable
[ERROR]       (argument mismatch; com.example.SampleTextIO.AddFieldFn cannot be converted to org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ProcessFunction)
[ERROR]     method org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements.via(org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.SerializableFunction) is not applicable
[ERROR]       (argument mismatch; com.example.SampleTextIO.AddFieldFn cannot be converted to org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.SerializableFunction)
[ERROR]     method org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements.via(org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Contextful) is not applicable
[ERROR]       (argument mismatch; com.example.SampleTextIO.AddFieldFn cannot be converted to org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Contextful)
```

Reading the [javadoc](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.13.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/MapElements.html), *MapElements* supports *Processfunction* but does not work well in my case.

How can I **dynamically** add fields like *python* in *java* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `via` method of `mapElements` expects one of the following: `InferableFunction`, `SimpleFunction`, `ProcessFunction`, `SerializableFunction`, `Contextful`. In your example `AddFieldFn` extends `DoFn` instead. Also, as per comparing with the Python example it seems that you want to output a list of two elements instead of yielding two different rows.

Three examples on how to do that:

```java
// via ProcessFunction
PCollection p1 = p.apply(Create.of(LINES))
  .apply(MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.lists(TypeDescriptors.strings()))
                    .via((String word) -> (Arrays.asList(word, "Its weekend!"))))
  .apply(ParDo.of(new PrintResultsFn()));

// via in-line SimpleFunction
PCollection p2 = p.apply(Create.of(LINES))
  .apply(MapElements.via(new SimpleFunction<String, List<String>>() {
    public List<String> apply(String word) {
      return Arrays.asList(word, "Its weekend!");
    }}))
  .apply(ParDo.of(new PrintResultsFn()));

// via AddFieldFn class 
PCollection p3 = p.apply(Create.of(LINES))
  .apply(MapElements.via(new AddFieldFn()))
  .apply(ParDo.of(new PrintResultsFn()));
```

where `AddFieldFn` is:

```java
// define AddFieldFn extending from SimpleFunction and overriding apply method
static class AddFieldFn extends SimpleFunction<String, List<String>> {
    @Override
    public List<String> apply(String word) {
        return Arrays.asList(word, "Its weekend!");
    }
}
```

and `PrintResultsFn` verifies the rows:

```java
// just print the results
static class PrintResultsFn extends DoFn<List<String>, Void> {
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(@Element List<String> words) {
        Log.info(Arrays.toString(words.toArray()));
    }
}
```

Which should print the desired output:

```java
Jun 23, 2019 8:00:03 PM com.dataflow.samples.SampleTextIO$PrintResultsFn processElement
INFO: [blah, Its weekend!]
Jun 23, 2019 8:00:03 PM com.dataflow.samples.SampleTextIO$PrintResultsFn processElement
INFO: [blah, Its weekend!]
Jun 23, 2019 8:00:03 PM com.dataflow.samples.SampleTextIO$PrintResultsFn processElement
INFO: [blah, Its weekend!]
```

Full code [here](https://gist.github.com/gxercavins/6daab0e7df265bde668803bbe4a010cc). Tested with DirectRunner and Java SDK 2.13.0

Comment: Thank you for the **A+** answer. Example code is what I really wanted.